# How to redirect local connection to my things in IPv6 on linux?

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, iptables, ip6tables

With IPv4 I can make some program connect to my service instead of where it wants using `REDIRECT` and `DNAT` targets in `OUTPUT` chain in iptables (sometimes combined with `-m owner`)

In IPv6 hovewer I don't see these things. The only related thing I see is TPROXY, but it is in `mangle` instead of `nat` and is said to be more complex to use, and I'm not sure it will work for local (not routed) connections.

How to manage and "recircuit" IPv6 connections of programs on GNU/Linux?